# ArcGIS 10.1 make Form onTop with C#

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, c#

I have a windows form which opens with my ICommand, referenses IApplication and does some staff with it( it is not relevent ). The problem is that I want it to be onTop within ArcMap, and minimized if ArcMap is minimized. Two obvious solutions doesn't satisfy my requirements.

1. Set form's *Topmost = true*. (Stays on top even if ArcMap is minimized.)
2. Use DockedWindow. I have actually around dozen of such forms, I don't want to change all the projects structure due to such minor requirement.

Is there a way to make windows form be "adopted" by ArcMap window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out there exists a solution online. Shortly, codes are like this.

add this class:

```
 public class ArcMapWindow : System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window
 {
    private IApplication m_app;

    public ArcMapWindow(IApplication application)
    {
        m_app = application;
    }

    public System.IntPtr Handle {
        get { return new IntPtr(m_app.hWnd); }
    }

 }
```

and use like that:

```
form.Show(new ArcMapWindow(m_application));
```

provided by: https://dbouwman.wordpress.com/2007/09/05/parenting-forms-to-arcmap-the-easy-way/